# Somewhat new programmer looking to make a camera application for PC - Don't know what language to use

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to make a Windows 7 PC based app that displays a live camera feed from a USB camera and then draw on it.  I don't know too much about programming but I'd like to learn.  I heard either C++, C#, or Visual Basic is the way to go.  For C++ or C#, do I only need to download Visual Studio and then start working?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest writing a few simpler applications before you dive into writing the application you need. You need to become more familiar with .NET in general, and you might get discouraged in doing so if you start off by writing a difficult application.

Comment: You could use eclipse for an IDE instead of Visual Studio, its free and has tons of community support and plugins.

Comment: +1 for going with C#. For your first project this thread will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211757/detect-an-object-in-a-camera-image-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Out of all of those languages, C# is easier to learn than C++, and will probably gain you more valuable programming experience than VB(C# is similar to Java, and is more in-demand professionally). It also integrates the best with .NET, which is what you'll probably use to interface with the webcam.

Get Visual C# Express and start hacking.

You may find [OpenCVdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) helpful in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You download Visual Studio 2010 Express and start working from there. It's a free version of the tool so add ons aren't available for it.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/

A quick Google search also brought up this nugget: http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/ which should be helpful.