# Recognize Person via Webcam and Fetch Old History Data

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am working on a new application in C# where I want to do some automatic functionalities.

I have a CRM in my office where new visitors come and get a visitor ticket using Kiosk, where they click photo, enter details.

Now I want to recognize the live pic and fetch the user details if user was appeared before or not.

Developing in C# WPF.

Anybody hlep me into this, to understand which platform or APIS will help me into this.?

Answer (score 0):

The key to this question is the recognition of people in images.

Please refer to the following data.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNX74NNeieI
2. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Finding-the-faces-in-in-e99bd310
3. [Detect an object in a camera image in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211757/detect-an-object-in-a-camera-image-in-c-sharp)