# How to detect objects in an image in c#?

Tags: c#, python, opencv, object-detection, yolo

I am building a C# project to detect all objects in the image , I don't want it to detect what is these objects , I just want it to detect the position of the objects in the image .

I have tried many ways to do it like [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-10-lines-of-code-d6cb4d86f606) (using imageai python library then I used this script in c#) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeiIppt-Xtw&t=2s) (using Alturos.Yolo library) tutorials, but these tutorials detect the known objects only but did not detect the position of an object if it do not know what is this object .

What I need is to detect the position of the object whether it recognize what is this object or not .

For example in this image

[image]

it detects the only the objects it recognize their type but I want it to detect all the objects in the image.

python code :

```
detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = 
detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , rel_path ,file_name), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path ,new_file_name))
for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : " , eachObject["percentage_probability"] ," : "  ,eachObject["box_points"]  )
```

using Alturos.Yolo library code :

```
var configurationDetector = new ConfigurationDetector();
var config = configurationDetector.Detect();

using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper(config))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        var items = yoloWrapper.Detect(ms.ToArray());
        yoloItemBindingSource.DataSource = items;
        arr = items.ToArray();
    }
}
```

can anyone help or recommend another way please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211757/detect-an-object-in-a-camera-image-in-c-sharp) is a similar question with some answers that may help you. Here are a few options I have found:

[AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/)

Some Methods:

```
* ColorFiltering
* ChannelFiltering
* HSLFiltering
* YCbCrFiltering
* EuclideanColorFiltering
```

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/)